# Reading JSON file using json-smart

Tags: java, json

I am trying to read the values from a JSON file to array for further processing. I am using JSON-Smart 1.2.0 library for the same. Due to some restrictions, I can not use the 2.0 version.

I am getting the following exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minidev.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to net.minidev.json.JSONObject
```

I am even tried using JSONArray instead of JSONObject. What I am doing wrong over here? Is this correct way to read json content?

Below is the java code.

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(browsers);
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) json.get("friends");

for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject cap = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
    String first = (String) cap.get("name");
    System.out.println(first);
}
```

Below is the json file content.

```
[
  {
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "test1"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON contains an array which has one single object element so you should parse it like that:

```
JSONArray root = (JSONArray) JSONValue.parseWithException(json);
JSONObject rootObj = (JSONObject) root.get(0);
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) rootObj.get("friends");

for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject cap = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
    String first = (String) cap.get("name");
    System.out.println(first);
}
```

If it can have more elements add a for loop instead of `root.get(0)`.

Comment: Is it possible to have the json file without the root named "friends"?

Comment: Yes, you could have a JSON like this: `[{"id":0,"name":"test1"},{"id":1,"name":"test2"}]`

Comment: In that case you could leave the 2nd and 3rd lines and iterate through the root.