# ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of:

Tags: json, jmeter, beanshell

Getting below error when i run the jmeter script having Beanshell Post Processor as a child to a sampler.

> [ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method:
>   eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBW5y.png) ``try { newuser=
>   vars.get("prevUsrResponse"); org.json.JSONObject userJSON= new o . . .
>   '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: org.json.JSONObject not found
>   in namespace

Below is the code written and run in jMeter 2.9.

```
newuser= vars.get("prevUsrResponse");
org.json.JSONObject userJSON= new org.json.JSONObject(newuser);

if(prevUsrJSON.has("User") && custJSON.get("User")!= null) {
   org.json.JSONObject contactJSON = userJSON.getJSONObject("User");

  contactJSON.put("UserType","Private");

}

vars.put("updatedUser", userJSON.toString());
```

`${updatedUser}` variable doesn't return the json(or any value) when used in the next sampler request.

Answer (score 0):

There can be the following possible reasons:

1. You don't have the .jar which provides org.json.JSONObject class in JMeter CLASSPATH.

   - Download the jar i.e. from the [Maven central repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160212)
   - Copy it to JMeter's "lib" folder
   - Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
2. You dont have the relevant import line. Add it to the beginning of your script:

   ```
   import org.json.JSONObject;
   ```

You can also consider upgrading to [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) which comes with built-in JSON support and provides [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) to extract data from JSON responses. If you still want Beanshell - it is also possible, just use [json-smart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185155/reading-json-file-using-json-smart) classes

Comment: BeanShellPostProcessor fails in JMeter 3.0 with the same error as mentioned above. I cannot use JSON Path PostProcessor in my case.Please help