# Extract json values in beanshell script

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

This is my json i want to extract firstname and code using beanshell script.But i'm not able to extract the values .
Please help

```
{  
   "code":"HNYC",
   "message":"Sucess",
   "data":{  
      "Employeid":"TGRDH-887",
      "Perosonal":{  
         "Details":{  
            "firstname":"Sam",
            "id":3566,
            "dob":"23/11/1990",
            "Yearofjoing":"2018",
            "Salary":30000,
            "Address":"New Delhi",
            "City":"Delhi"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Beanshell Code:

```
import com.eclipsesource.json.JsonObject;
String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString();  
JsonObject accountId = JsonObject.readFrom(jsonString); 
String code = accountId.getJSONObject("code");   
print("value "+code);
```

Comment: @SuhasBachhav this is java, not javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do you know about [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)? If not - consider using it as it provides possibility to fetch JSON data using simple [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries like `$..code` and `$.. firstname`

---

If you still want to go for scripting be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) for any form of scripting. Groovy is more "modern" language than Beanshell, it supports all new Java features and it has a lot of [enhancements](http://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) on top of Java SDK

One of them is built-in JSON support via [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) class, so you can shorten your code to something like:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())
String code = json.code
log.info(code)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 1):

You can get `code` value directly from JSONObject, since it is property in JSONObject [refer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parse-json-java/)

```
String code = accountId.get("code");
```

Comment: I got below error when i tried above 
Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval 
Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import com.eclipsesource.json.JsonObject;  
String jsonString = prev.getResponseD . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: JsonObject not found in namespace

Comment: did you have JSON library in your class path?

Comment: yes i have minimal-json-0.9.2.jar in lib of my jmeter,
and also i have imported below import
import com.eclipsesource.json.JsonObject;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37855894/error-jmeter-util-beanshellinterpreter-error-invoking-bsh-method-evalsource?rq=1, check this and once again check import statement

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject getData = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
JSONObject getPerosonal = getData.getJSONObject("Perosonal");
JSONObject getDetails = getPerosonal.getJSONObject("Details");
Object firstname= getDetails.get("firstname");

System.out.println(firstname);
```

Comment: Use import org.json.simple.JSONObject; package or find the equivalent in import com.eclipsesource.json.JsonObject;