# How to update JSON node value in jmeter using beanshell preprocessor

Tags: json, jmeter, beanshell

Currently, I am trying to update the JSON response node value using BeanShell PreProcessor.

Need help in converting JSON response in Object and then updating the node value and then stringify.

I have the following JSON and I want to update the OrderTypeId and IsCredentialOff values using BeanShell PreProcessor in Jmeter. I have tried a solution in postman which worked well. whereas getting difficulty in BeanShell Scripting.

```
{"DeliveryCharge":0.0,"ApplyCouponToCart":true,"CartId":6970,"SessionId":"DB84A55E-82A9-4BC9-98E8-2A845FB6893A","StoreId":10061,"UserId":10011690,"AppId":10061,"ListCartItem":[{"CartItemId":55513,"UserId":0,"StoreId":0,"AppId":0,"CartId":6970,"PID":772544,"Pack":1,"ProductId":5712,"ProductImage":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.liquorapps.com/sm/000457-TWO-FINGERS-GOLD-TEQUILA.png","ProductName":"TWO FINGERS GOLD","UnitSize":"750 ML","Quantity":1,"UPC":"89540135328","SKU":"1014","CategoryId":2,"TypeId":15,"VarietalId":0,"UnitSizeId":12,"CountryId":7,"RegionId":32,"Price":14.99,"PriceDisplay":"$14.99","OfferPrice":14.99,"OfferPriceDisplay":"$14.99","FinalPrice":14.99,"FinalPriceDisplay":"$14.99","TaxRate":0.066250,"QuantityOrdered":1,"Remark":"","ItemTotal":14.99,"ItemTotalDisplay":"$14.99","FinalItemTotal":14.99,"FinalItemTotalDisplay":"$14.99","ItemTotalSaving":0.00,"ItemTotalSavingDisplay":"","ListDiscount":[],"ListCharge":[],"CartItemCount":0,"Deposit":0.00,"DealId":0,"DealInventory":0,"DealInventoryMessage":"","IsBottleLimitAtRetail":false,"TotalQuantity":1,"IsOfferItem":false,"SuccessMessage":"","ErrorDetail":"","ErrorMessage":"","MessageType":"","MessageTitle":"","TextType":""}],"ListDiscount":[],"ListCharge":[],"CouponCode":"","OrderTypeId":1,"AddressId":0,"PaymentTypeId":0,"TipForDriver":0.00,"ListTipForDriver":[],"SubTotal":14.99,"SubTotalDisplay":"$14.99","TotalSavings":0.0,"TotalSavingsDisplay":"-$0.00","TotalCharges":0.0,"TotalChargesDisplay":"$0.00","TotalValue":14.99,"TotalValueDisplay":"$14.99","SubTotalAfterDsicount":14.99,"SubTotalAfterDiscountDisplay":"$14.99","CartPaymentItemUser":{"UserId":10011690,"StoreId":10061,"AppId":0,"PaymentTypeId":0,"UserProfileId":"","IsDefault":false,"IsCardDefault":false,"Credential1":"","Credential2":"UdVYyaeBH+IBzsetzftdBw==","Credential3":"","IsLive":false},"DoPDate":"01/01/1900","DoPTimeSlot":"","DopUtcStartDate":"","DopUtcEndDate":"","Remark":"","DeliveryTax":0.0,"ShippingCost":0.0,"CartItemCount":1,"IsCredentialOff":false,"IsDeliverySolution":false,"DeliveryFeeMarkUp":0.0,"ShippingTax":0.0,"DeliveryTaxRate":0.0,"IsFromCheckOut":true,"IsUpgradeUser":true,"IsToCallDSP":false,"DeliveryInstruction":"","IsStoreCreditUtilize":false,"OrderRewardCredit":5.00,"OrderRewardCreditDisplay":"-$5.00","OrderTotalWithCredit":0.0,"IsStoreReward":false,"CouponRemark":"","IsShipping":false,"CartTotalQuan":1,"ShippingServiceCode":"","ActualDeliveryCharge":0.0,"EstimatedShippingCost":0.0,"ShippingDeliveryCharge":0.0,"DoordashValidateCustomer":false,"CustomerSessionId":13733,"ConvenienceFee":0.0,"IsDoCalculation":false,"SuccessMessage":"","ErrorDetail":"","ErrorMessage":"","MessageType":"","MessageTitle":"","TextType":""}
```

I have tried in BeanShell PreProcessor:

```
var CartGetDetailsObject = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
var jsonData  = JSON.parse(CartGetDetailsObject);
jsonData.OrderTypeId=2;
jsonData.IsCredentialOff=true;
vars.put("vCartGetDetailsObject",JSON.stringify(jsonData));
log.info(vCartGetDetailsObject);
```

Error Log

```
2020-04-06 12:56:48,139 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2020-04-06 12:56:48,145 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2020-04-06 12:56:48,153 INFO o.a.j.r.ResultCollector: Folder at F:\Office\Performance Test Cases\BottlecappsJmeterPerformanceScripts\apache-jmeter-5.0\RunScript\Date 6-Apr-2020 125648 was created
2020-04-06 12:56:48,154 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2020-04-06 12:56:48,958 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2020-04-06 12:56:48,958 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2020-04-06 12:56:48,958 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2020-04-06 12:56:48,958 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=0 perThread=0.0 delayedStart=false
2020-04-06 12:56:48,984 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2020-04-06 12:56:48,984 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2020-04-06 12:56:48,986 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2020-04-06 12:56:48,987 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: F:\Office\Performance Test Cases\BottlecappsJmeterPerformanceScripts\apache-jmeter-5.0\testrundata.csv
2020-04-06 12:56:53,982 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``var CartGetDetailsObject = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); var jsonData  = JSON. . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: parse() on undefined variable or class name: JSON
2020-04-06 12:56:53,982 WARN o.a.j.m.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script. org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``var CartGetDetailsObject = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); var jsonData  = JSON. . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: parse() on undefined variable or class name: JSON
2020-04-06 12:56:54,645 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPJavaImpl: readResponse: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://staging.liquorapps.com/Bcapi/api/Cart/CartUpdate
2020-04-06 12:56:54,645 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPJavaImpl: Cause: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://staging.liquorapps.com/Bcapi/api/Cart/CartUpdate
2020-04-06 12:56:54,645 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPJavaImpl: Error Response Code: 400
2020-04-06 12:56:57,171 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``var CartGetDetailsObject = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); var jsonData  = JSON. . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: parse() on undefined variable or class name: JSON
2020-04-06 12:56:57,171 WARN o.a.j.m.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script. org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``var CartGetDetailsObject = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); var jsonData  = JSON. . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: parse() on undefined variable or class name: JSON
2020-04-06 12:56:57,389 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPJavaImpl: readResponse: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://staging.liquorapps.com/Bcapi/api/Cart/CartUpdate
2020-04-06 12:56:57,389 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPJavaImpl: Cause: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://staging.liquorapps.com/Bcapi/api/Cart/CartUpdate
2020-04-06 12:56:57,389 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPJavaImpl: Error Response Code: 400
2020-04-06 12:56:58,364 INFO o.a.j.g.a.Start: Stopping test
2020-04-06 12:56:58,377 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping: Thread Group 1-1
2020-04-06 12:56:58,377 WARN o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Interrupting: Thread Group 1-1 sampler: LoginCustomer
2020-04-06 12:56:58,382 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2020-04-06 12:56:58,383 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2020-04-06 12:56:58,383 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Close: F:\Office\Performance Test Cases\BottlecappsJmeterPerformanceScripts\apache-jmeter-5.0\testrundata.csv
2020-04-06 12:56:58,385 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Comment: Great, your first question here! Possibly it is a duplicate of [Extract json values in beanshell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53220485)? Please check, maybe you'll get answer there. Also, for writing good questions in StackOverflow, I'd suggest you to check this help center page: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) is a standard built-in object for Web API, you can run it in Postman because Postman is an [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/apps/postman) application (browser). JMeter isn't a browser therefore you cannot use `JSON` functions.

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def jsonData = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
   jsonData.OrderTypeId = 2
   jsonData.IsCredentialOff = true
   vars.put("vCartGetDetailsObject", new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(jsonData).toPrettyString())
   log.info(vars.get('vCartGetDetailsObject'))
   ```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)